# Можно ли использовать CollapsingToolbarLayout для других элементов, кроме Toolbar?

Tags: java, android, collapsing-toolbar-layout

Можно ли использовать CollapsingToolbarLayout не только для сплющивания Toolbar, но и для других элементов. К примеру TextView с какой-нибудь инфой, полями для ввода текста. Например, заполнил их, нажал кнопку и внизу появился пункт списка. И если это список начать листать вниз, то TextView и остальные элементы сплющатся и исчезнут.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно. Просто поместите свою разметку в `CollapsingToolbarLayout` указав ей как реагировать на скролл через аттрибут `app:layout_collapseMode`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
            <!-- сюда можно поместить всё, что угодно -->
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```